# How to get nginx.conf include directive to ignore .bak files

Tags: nginx

How do I get the [include directory for ngnix conf files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) to ignore `*.bak`?

I back up my configuration files, for example default -> default.bak. I want to include `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` but not `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.bak` in `nginx.conf`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend changing default to default.conf or another extension if possible , then include can properly differentiate from config and bak.

```
http {

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;


}
```